# Who is Uncle Marv?

Tags: support, area-51

I went Area51 [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=life). There in the **Who is this site for?** section I see a strange warning as below: (to see it, focus the "This site is for" text box)

[image: Who is Uncle Marv?]

Is this a random name? or any fun behind that?
Because I can't find any reference for the Uncle Marv in Internet.

Quoting the message for better future search:

> Your site should focus on pilots, not passengers; lawyers, not lawbreakers; professional photographers, not **Uncle Marv** with his digital point-n-shoot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the word 'Uncle' implies family / (or [sometimes acquaintance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157973/where-did-the-usage-of-uncle-to-refer-to-unrelated-individuals-come-from)).

Marv is just a name. Because every uncle has a name. Nobody special (as far as I know)

In this case it's just an English-language colloquial way of differentiating someone who is not a professional.

Here it's translated as: "It's for people who know what they're doing. Not for amateurs".

Comment: Nice! [This blog post](http://infinitepose-abilities.com/blog/?p=43) can be used as reference, it describes the "uncle" part in an awesome way... :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nice article Uncle Shadow. However it now makes me realise I'm basically 'Uncle Bob' at most things I do. Sadly, even professionally.

Comment: Also ,related question on English.SE site: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20346/bobs-your-uncle-no-hes-not

Comment: @ShadowWizard [Well, I'll be a monkey's uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey%27s_uncle).

Comment: lol, looks like we both learn tons of new terms today... :-D

Answer (score 7):

[image]

It's really just a commentary on how your uncle, who isn't a professional photographer (but thinks he is), doesn't need a site.

Comment: That is...not a Google image search I'm going to be repeating.